# Get the top 5 items based on count and date in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking to get the top 5 items in a table but within a certain time period, say 7 days.

This is the table structure and some random example data

```
 user_id | entry_id |   sig  |    timestamp
 1          1           8846    2015-03-27 20:49:56 
 1          2           8846    2015-03-27 20:49:56 
 1          3           8846    2015-03-27 20:49:56 
 1          4           4544    2015-03-27 20:49:56 
 1          5           4544    2015-03-27 20:49:56 
 1          6           65445   2015-03-27 20:49:56
```

User_id is unique, entry_id is primary key.

So for example I want to query the **sig** column to count the number of occurrences for each number within a time period of 7 days say 8846 appears 20 times.

This is the SQL query I have so far which counts the number of occurrences but not within a period of time. Its basic for the moment just need a working example.

```
SELECT sig, count(sig), sig_count FROM event 
GROUP BY sig
ORDER BY sig_count
DESC LIMIT 5;
```

**(EDIT) Additional details**
I phrased the question incorrectly previously. What I really meant to say is I need to get the top 5 **sigs** based on occurrences within a time period of the last 7 days and return those records. The data will be used to populate a graph of sorts.

So for example if i can get the result and then using PHP, I can take the entry_id and loop through it to get the timestamp and number of occurrences(frequency 'x' time 'y') and and pop it into a graph.

I guess a first query gets the count results. Then a second query could be run to get that particular sig id and all the records associated with in the last 7 days.

Any contribution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Within 7 days of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, this is an aggregation with a `where` clause:

```
select sig, count(*) as sig_count
from table t
where timestamp >= date_sub(now(), interval 7 day)
group by sig
order by sig_count desc
limit 5;
```

Comment: That works perfectly in getting the counts, thank you. I modified the question. Would it be simple enough to return all the records as well. I need to create a dataset for a graph that will have a y axis of occurrence and a x axis of each day in the 7 day period. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have the same time frame for each group (within 7 days differs per row), you have to use a subquery to get the count within 7 days per row, which will be slow but I'm not sure there's another way to do it.

```
select sig, max(sig_count)
from (
    select sig,
        (select count(*) from event e2
        where e2.sig = e1.sig
        and e2.timestamp between date_sub(e1.timestamp,interval 7 day)
            and date_add(e1.timestamp,interval 7 day)) as sig_count
    from event e1
) t1 group by sig
order by max(sig_count) desc
limit 5
```

Comment: I did have a comment saying it didn't work but seems to have gone. I must of typed it in wrong. Im running the query now. its been one minute so far and is still going. I have around 30000 records. :p

Comment: any suggestions on increasing speed? The record count could go into the hundreds of thousands within a month or 2. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @rkleman12 I would save the 7 day counts to the db and update them each time I inserted a new event

Comment: @rkleman12 also a composite index on `(sig,timestamp)` would help

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will try them see if it helps. :)